# TypeError(RN 0.61.2): _firebaseApp.default.messaging is not a function

Tags: react-native, react-native-firebase

I am upgrading my app to react-native 0.61.2 so I had to upgrade react-native-firebase to 6.0.3,I start with adding `@react-native-firebase/app` and `@react-native-firebase/messaging` packages.

```
import { Platform } from 'react-native'
import { firebase } from '@react-native-firebase/messaging'

// pluck values from your `GoogleService-Info.plist` you created on the firebase console
const iosConfig = {
  clientId: '...',
  appId: '...',
  apiKey: '...',
  databaseURL: '...',
  storageBucket: '...',
  messagingSenderId: '...',
  projectId: '...',
  persistence: true,
}

// pluck values from your `google-services.json` file you created on the firebase console
const androidConfig = {
  clientId: '...',
  appId: '...',
  apiKey: '...',
  databaseURL: '...',
  storageBucket: '...',
  messagingSenderId: '...',
  projectId: '...',
  persistence: true,
}

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(
  // use platform-specific firebase config
  Platform.OS === 'ios' ? iosConfig : androidConfig,
  // name of this app
  'myApp'
)

export default firebaseApp
```

on my file I am doing this

```
import firebaseApp from '...path to/firebaseApp'
  .
  .
  .
  async checkPermission() {
    console.warn('checkPermission firebaseApp : ', firebaseApp)
    const enabled = await firebaseApp.messaging().hasPermission()
    if (!enabled) {
      this.requestPermission()
    }
    this.syncToken()
  }
  .
  .
  .
```

I am getting next **warnings**:

**Warning #1:**

```
 checkPermission firebaseApp :  {"_40": 0, "_55": {"_automaticDataCollectionEnabled": false, "_deleteApp": [Function bound deleteApp], "_deleted": false, "_initialized": false, "_intialized": true, "_name": "...", "_nativeInitialized": false, "_options": {"apiKey": "...", "appId": "...", "clientId": "...", "databaseURL": "...", "debug": true, "messagingSenderId": "...", "projectId": "...", "storageBucket": "..."}}, "_65": 1, "_72": null}
```

**Warning #2:**

```
Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
TypeError: _firebaseApp.default.messaging is not a function. (In '_firebaseApp.default.messaging()', '_firebaseApp.default.messaging' is undefined)
```

am I doing something wrong, any help?

Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

I should use the default  app 
so in my `initializeApp` I removed the second option `myApp`
and 
this method changed to be

```
async checkPermission() {
    console.warn('checkPermission firebaseApp : ', firebaseApp)
    firebaseApp
    const enabled = await firebase.messaging().hasPermission()
    if (!enabled) {
      this.requestPermission()
    }
    this.syncToken()
  }
```

reading firebase from

```
   import firebase from '@react-native-firebase/app'
   import '@react-native-firebase/messaging'
```

Answer (score 0):

From react native 0.60.0. React native introduce [Autolinking](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/master/docs/autolinking.md) library feature, so there is no need to manually linking library or npm in android and ios, but we are used some old packages and libraries. Those npm(react-native-firebase) are not updated according to new version of react native, so we need to link those libraries and packages manually.

**You need to check firebase npm manually linking process.**

**1. import package name into `MainActivity.java` file**

[image]

**2. Add following dependency in `app` level `build.gradle` file**

[image]

**3. Add `classpath` in `project` level `build.gradle` file**

[image]

Comment: Thank you @vishal-dhanotiya , we were trying to upgrade react-native-firebase to `6.0.3` following this link https://invertase.io/oss/react-native-firebase/migrating-to-v6
but we kept things as is, using old version and manual linking for this package